# Free Groups Are Torsion-Free: proof using cyclically reduced words

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

I am trying to show that

> free groups (defined via the universal property) are torsion-free.

I have a hint that says that I should first consider words that are cyclically reduced. That is, if $s_1,...,s_k$ are the generators, then  $w=s_i...s_l$ is cyclically reduced if $s_i\neq s_l^{-1}$.

Now clearly cyclically reduced words are torsion-free but I am unsure how I can go on to use this to show that all words are torsion-free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Every word is the *conjugate* of a cyclically reduced word. That is, every word $V$ has the form $V\equiv UWU^{-1}$ where $W$ is cyclically reduced and $U$ is a freely reduced word.

(I am going by the hint you have been given, not by your comment about using the universal property. As far as I am concerned, this does not use the universal property of free groups in any explicit way...)

Comment: Ok, thanks. How do I show that every has this form?

Comment: Do I just reduce cyclically till I can't anymore and then it must have this form?

Comment: Yes, exactly! If a word isn't cyclically reduced then shift it until it is. This corresponds to conjugating by the bits which cancel when you form $VV$.